# Change title size and color in Quarto (html output)

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I have a quarto file with an HTML rendering, and I want to change the size and color of the title, how should I proceed?
Minimal example:

````
---
title: "Cars"
format: 
  html
---

## MTCars
```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

Comment: This could also help: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73546631/how-to-format-tabset-font-in-quarto/73546972#73546972)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `css` directly in your code; specify `.title` to apply your changes to the title only.

With `font-size`, you can change the size of the title, and with `color` you can change the color. You can also change the style with `font-style`, the family (e.g. Arial) with `font-family`, and the variant with `font-variant`.

````
---
title: "Cars"
format: 
  html
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}
.title {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: blue;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

## MTCars
```{r}
head(mtcars)
```
````

[image]